# path not recognized by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, path, routes

My app is calling a resource trougth a path helper `show_popular_hashtags_path`, but Rails seems to not recognize it. This is my partial:

```
.col-xs-12.no-padding.blue-title{style: "page-break-inside: avoid !important;"}
  .col-xs-12.text-center.global-map.no-padding
    %h1 
      = t('uniq.hashtag.title')
    .js-column-chart-hashtags{data: {url: show_popular_hashtags_path(id: @project.id, provider: provider), provider: provider}}
      .column-chart-hashtags.statistics-chart{class: "#{provider}", style: "width: 100%"}
    %h2.empty-message.column-chart-hashtags{class: "#{provider}", style: "padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 30px; display: none;"}
      = t('unique.there_is_no_info')
```

this is my `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :user do
  resources :projects, except: [:delete] do
    member do
      get :show_users, to: 'projects#js_show_users_data', as: :show_users_data
      get :show_popular_hashtags, to: 'projects#js_show_popular_hashtags', as: :show_popular_hashtags
      get :show_activity_data, to: 'projects#js_show_activity_data', as: :show_activity_data
```

For the another routes everything goes very well, even when I run `rake routes | grep show_popular_hashtags`, the output is:

```
$ rake routes | grep show_popular_hashtags
    show_popular_hashtags_user_project GET      /user/projects/:id/show_popular_hashtags(.:format)       user/projects#js_show_popular_hashtags
```

So, this looks like the route is well, but when I visit the view which contains the partial this error appears:

```
undefined method `show_popular_hashtags_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa20d865d10>:0x007fa20dc5a6f0>
```

I already restarted the server, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your routes helper is actually `show_popular_hashtags_user_project`, not `show_popular_hashtags`.  You can see it in the first column of the `rake routes` output:

```
$ rake routes | grep show_popular_hashtags
    show_popular_hashtags_user_project GET      /user/projects/:id/show_popular_hashtags(.:format)       user/projects#js_show_popular_hashtags
```

Just change the name of the `show_popular_hashtags` routes helper to `show_popular_hashtags_user_project` in your view, and it will work.

Comment: It worked, I did not try it because the similar path for other routes worked without `namespace` and `resource`. Thank you!